# How to properly "wait" for a transaction to confirm?

Tags: transactions, rpc, signature, jsonrpc-api, send-transaction

**What I have tried**

I've previously used the `@web3/solana` npm package, but ended up having to create my own (private) library due to using a niche language.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Serialize and sign a transaction (via a 3rd party)
- Send the signed transaction
- Wait for the transaction to be processed, and confirm its validity

Here is what I tried:

- Serialize and sign the transaction
- Send the transaction via [sendTransaction](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#sendtransaction) rpc method
- Wait for the transaction to be committed via [signatureSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#signaturesubscribe)
- Use [getTransaction](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction) to confirm the transaction details, assuming the call to `signatureSubscribe` did not close its connection early, and received a `signatureNotification` payload

**What the problem is**

I've noticed that `signatureSubscribe` can sometimes abruptly close my connection.
This results in my program thinking the transaction is invalid, when the transaction is actually valid.

Is this "transaction confirmation" strategy flawed? If a connection to `signatureSubscribe` errors, should it be retried?
How can I know for certain whether or not a transaction is fully valid/invalid after sending it via the rpc method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transaction confirmation is a hard problem, which is why the current web3.js code can be very confusing!

The way it currently works is:

- use `signatureSubscribe` in one promise, wait to get a confirmation at the level that you care about (`processed` / `confirmed` / `finalized`)
- in parallel, use `getSignatureStatuses` to see if it's already been confirmed https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getsignaturestatuses

An older transaction won't create new notifications, so you could get a false negative if you just do `signatureSubscribe`, so you should also do `getSignatureStatuses` at first.

And finally, you can be sure that a transaction is fully invalid when the cluster has reached the block height for its blockhash, meaning that the blockhash is no longer valid. This is provided as `lastValidBlockHeight` when you fetch the blockhash. You can do this by polling `getBlockHeight` in parallel.

You can see the full web3.js code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/e76bea942df606a292e845d634db87d6dbf438ce/packages/library-legacy/src/connection.ts#L3840