# How to reliably detect sendtransaction confirmation errors?

Tags: send-transaction

When I broadcast a Transaction that is about to expire with SendTransaction, no error is returned from the node, but the Tx may not be taken into the network.

Is there any way to reliably detect this in SendTransaction?

now, Currently skipPreflight, preflightCommitment and maxRetries are not specified and are defaults.

If maxRetries is set to 0, no retries would be made. This way, can we reliably track SendTransaction failures?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly "wait" for a transaction to confirm?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6062/how-to-properly-wait-for-a-transaction-to-confirm)

Answer (score 1):

I think this post/response might be what you need: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6088/121.

The [confirmTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#confirmTransaction) method might be sufficient for what you are trying to do (or [sendAndConfirmTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/functions/sendAndConfirmTransaction.html) which just uses `sendAndConfirmTransaction` under the hood).

Here are some good resources if you'd like to dig in a little deeper and/or create custom polling/retry logic:

- [Transaction Confirmation](https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions/confirmation)
- [Solana Cookbook - Retrying Transactions](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#facts)
- [Guide: Handling Dropped Transactions](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/transactions/solana-transaction-propagation-handling-dropped-transactions)

Depeneding on your use case, you might try the [experimental version of Solana/Web3.js](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/tree/master/packages/library#retry-logic), which allows building in custom retry logic.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am using another development language, not web3.js.

Can the SendTransaction response confirm the success or failure of the Transaction?

Should I use GetSignatureStatuses?

Comment: Yeah--i actually think `confirmTransaction` is using `getSignatureStatuses` under the hood. Here's the [source/polling logic](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/056930483531424f2ef584be8aeaa1cee56b0db7/rpc-client/src/nonblocking/rpc_client.rs#L688).

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/transactions/solana-transaction-propagation-handling-dropped-transactions#check-if-the-transaction-succeeded-or-if-blockhash-has-expired), it seems that the lastValidBlockHeight of getLatestBlockHash is kept, getBlockHeight is retrieved after SendTransaction, and the expiration date is checked to see if 150 slots have passed from the lastValidBlockHeight.

Comment: Can the [isBlockhashValid](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/isblockhashvalid) Method do the same thing? Which method would be more reliable?