Private RPC issue "TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature has expired: block height exceeded" when confirming successful transaction
Error am getting
"TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature XXX has expired: block height exceeded" when confirming successful transaction
const confirmation = await this.solanaConnection1.confirmTransaction({ signature: txid, blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight }, 'confirmed');
My this request fails when i used Private RPC network such as
Quick node: https://chaotic-greatest-shard.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/api-key or
syndica : https://solana-mainnet.api.syndica.io/api-key/
But it works fine with public solana RPC network
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
the problem with public RPC it allows only 10 RPC request per ip

check out this answer https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6088/1708

This question is similar to: How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
